# Alternate word for impersonate in terms of Items or things

Tags: grammar, verbs, vocabulary, sentence

Well actually I'm searching for the right word for a particular scenario or maybe behavior.

Suppose I go to a shop and ask for an item but they don't have it. Now the sales person's priority is to make a sale and he ***impersonates***
(I know  it's not the right word) another item and tells me it's what I'm looking for.

What word do I use in place of impersonation?

Comment: how 'bout "*substitutes*"?

Comment: You mean he 'suggests' another item?

Comment: @Josh61 not suggests but tries to make me buy another stuff saying it's better although it may not be ...

Comment: The word most people would use here is very probably 'suggests'; 'offers [me]' probably comes second. Have you a different example which works better (when 'substitutes', as Jim suggests, might well work?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth well it's more in a negative sense what I'm looking for. `Suggest` seem quite positive

Comment: You may be referring to  'hard sell' practice.

Comment: 'Push' has this sense, but wouldn't work too well in this case (it's more the practice over time), and is considered slang, as in [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/push): 9. Slang
a. To promote or sell (a product) >>

Comment: There seems to be a thin line between promoting a product to sell and cheating a customer by selling what may not be what he wants. So 'Push' may seem like the word

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ok ..dats sounds better

Comment: @EdwinAshworth would you mind posting this as answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you're happy with a multi-word verb.

The MWV 'fob off', which is transitive (compulsorily separable with pronouns: *fob us off*) can take a with- (prepositional) phrase, is perhaps the best choice; I'd say it's informal rather than slang:

The sense is spelled out at [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/FOB)

> .2. **fob off**
>
> a. to induce someone to take (something inferior)

I asked for 'Bogdan', but he tried to fob me off with 'Sergei'.

Comment: 'fob' deliveries this feeling of the sales person trying to deceive, cheat. I definitely need to keep that in mind next time not to use that word on some kind-hearted recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... I don't think any English words will fit in this situation. I recommend to use "suggest"and describe more in details if you would like to elaborate it.

There is a jargon-"bait-and-switch". However, it is a noun and not exactly what you want.

I think @EdwinAshworth's word choice is excellent!

Comment: I agree that @EdwinAshworth choice is perfect

Answer (score 0):

"Impersonate" is definitely *not* the word you want, as "impersonate" suggests that a different object is trying to be the one the customer is looking for. Jim's "substitute", and Josh61's "suggests" are both good choices, but in the example you cite, I'd personally use "recommends".

Answer (score 0):

Aside from suggest, the salesperson may be trying to `market` the substitute item...?

> *to do things that cause people to know about and want to buy (something)*

(From [Merriam](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/market))